# Operator not applicable to this operand type when casting interfaces

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I've been working with a 3rd party service for the last couple days in Delphi XE2, and just about have it done. I'm running into a a problem that is absolutely stumping me that I think should have very obvious answers. I'm hoping another set of eyes can tell me what my problem is.

I have this interface:

```
IWorshipTeamEvent = Interface(IInterface)
  function GetId : integer;
  function GetName : string;
  function GetTeamId : integer;
  function GetStartDate : TDate;
  function GetEndDate : TDate;
  function GetStartTime : TTime;
  function GetEndTime : TTime;
  function GetSets : IWorshipTeamSetList;

  property Id : integer read GetId;
  property Name : string read GetName;
  property TeamId : integer read GetTeamId;
  property StartDate : TDate read GetStartDate;
  property EndDate : TDate read GetEndDate;
  property StartTime : TTime read GetStartTime;
  property EndTime : TTime read GetEndTime;
  property Sets : IWorshipTeamSetList read GetSets;
end;
```

Then in another class in the same unit, I'm trying to return a `IWorshipTeamEvent` in this function:

```
function TWorshipTeamEventList.GetEvent(index: Integer) : IWorshipTeamEvent;
begin
  //fEvents is a TInterfaceList that contains only IWorshipTeamEvents
  Result := fEvents[index] as IWorshipTeamEvent;
end;
```

At this point, I got the compiler error `Operator not applicable to this operand type`. I've tried a few things, like creating a `temp` variable with the type of `IXmlResponseType` and going

```
temp := fEvents[index] as IXmlResponseType;
Result := nil;
```

which compiled, so I tried creating `temp` with a type of `IWorshipTeamEvent` and going

```
temp := fEvents[index] as IWorshipTeamEvent;
Result := nil;
```

which did not compile.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast a TInterfacedObject to an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448013/cast-a-tinterfacedobject-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5422146/1224272) answer on another question which pointed out that the GUID was missing. After Generating a GUID for my `IWorshipTeamEvent` interface, everything compiles and works as expected.